# App to send commands over telnet?

Tags: applications

I have a home appliance which I would like to control over TCP/IP - telnet - protocol. Do I need to design and program my own app for that or is there a shorter way to success? Some "universal remote control" with controls and buttons that I could bind to specific telnet commands to a pre-configured IP address?

I have some generic Android on the phone (it should work on my Android 9 and any number of versions that other household members have) and on the other side is an AV receiver with some proprietary software that understands commands sent over telnet (no SSH on that one). Since it's all on the home network, security is of a lesser concern.

Comment: Telnet is insecure, consider `ssh`. `ssh` also has more powers. And can you update the question, to tell us what you have (operating system) at each end of the connection.

Comment: Telnet is a simple protocol. You mostly just text over a TCP socket. So you need to open a TCP socket, then send lines of text to the device. I would prototype in python (on my desktop/laptop), then move it to termux (a Gnu/Linux environment (app), for android), then add a button (using the termux button extension). Then (maybe) write a native app.